# Custom sensitivity settings on gyroscope through android api, or kernel?

Tags: android, kernel, sensors, gyroscope

I own a samsung galaxy tab 10.1 4g lte-- and am starting to play with the sensors onboard. I looked up the mems [gyro on board](http://invensense.com/cn/mems/gyro/documents/PS-MPU-3000A-00_v2.5.pdf) and found that (you can see for yourself on pg 9) that there are 4 different condition settings to change the sensitivity of the gyro from 250 degrees per second to up to like 2500 degrees per second. I am pretty sure that the lower setting will allow for a finer resolution of reading, while the higher settings can account for larger amounts of motions ( the reading at highest resolution (250) would probably max out at 250). Does anyone know what the default setting is and how to change it? If i had to guess I would bet the setting is on +-500 or +-1000 by default.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On registering your listener, you can specify the rate at which the events should be received.

```
registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)
```

You can choose from a variety of rates enumerated by SensorManager class:

```
SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST
```

Moreover, even the rate values are just a hint for the system, it's not necessarily receiving events at your specified rate.